# Prints are clumpy, uneven and "gloopy"

Tags: bambu

Pictures tell the story. Either the printing layers are uneven sizes or they clumo at the beginning and end of the print.
Bambu P1P with a generic PLA and all default settings with auto generated tree supports. Top and bottom areas should be sharp points, not this mess

[image: gross print]

Comment: Looks like you are printing slow and with too much temperature, could you share your basic speed and temperature settings? Please by [edit]!

Comment: Also post a picture of how the object should look, part screen shot or something from STL or sliced object.

Comment: Broken cooling fan, maybe?